# problem with pallets bounties & treasury

Tags: substrate-node-template, runtime, pallet-treasury, pallet-bounties

hello I am trying to add the bounties pallet to the substrate node-template. the version I am using is "release-polkadot-v1.7.0". I keep getting
the following error:

```
the traitframe\_support::traits::fungibles::Mutate\<AccountId32> is not implemented for pallet\_balances::Pallet\<Runtime> , which is required by sp\_runtime::generic::Block\<sp\_runtime::generic::Header\<u32, sp\_runtime::traits::BlakeTwo256>, sp\_runtime::generic::UncheckedExtrinsic\<MultiAddress\<AccountId32, ()>, RuntimeCall, MultiSignature, (CheckNonZeroSender\<Runtime>, CheckSpecVersion\<Runtime>, CheckTxVersion\<Runtime>, CheckGenesis\<Runtime>, CheckEra\<Runtime>, CheckNonce\<Runtime>, CheckWeight\<Runtime>, ChargeTransactionPayment\<Runtime>)>>: sp\_runtime::traits::Block\
```

I really don't understand, as I don't change the implementation of frame_system and pallet-balances, I only add pallet-treasury and pallet-bounties in the runtime.

I also started from a clean updated substrate node-template, and the error clearly appears after adding pallet-treasury & pallet-bounties. I first added pallet-collective, and this one works fine. the following line seems to be responsible:

```
 #[derive_impl(frame_system::config_preludes::SolochainDefaultConfig as frame_system::DefaultConfig)]
```

Also,  in pallet-treasury implementation, the following line gives me a type mismatch error. However, I see it used in several other runtimes:

```
type Paymaster = PayFromAccount<Balances, TreasuryAccount>;
```

Thanks in advance for your help,
Kazu

Comment: Hey, could you please provide a repo with the code that's failing to compile?